# Working with an Array of Objects

Tags: java, arrays, object

@edit IT works, thanks for the answers:) I guess my bad was when I thought that

```
WORLD[i]=global.Values.CHUNKPATTERN();
```

simply takes the object on the right, clones its value('s), and assigns them to part on the left, while it turns out that it establishes a reference between two. Thanks again:)

I have simple begginer/newbie array problem:

```
for(int i=0; i<global.Values.WORLDVOLUME(); i++)  
// global.Values.WORLDVOLUME() --> const, int. always the same.
{
WORLD[i]=global.Values.CHUNKPATTERN(); //to pre-define as 'zero only' object. Always the same. Const.
WORLD[i].chunknr=i+1;
}

System.out.println(WORLD[4].chunknr);
```

Of course I want `WORLD[0]` to have chunknr 1, `WORLD[4]` to have chunknr of 5 and so on.

Instead `WORLD[i].chunknr=i+1;`  seems to update chunknr of ALL elements(not only `WORLD[i]`).
So that it looks like `WORLD[0].chunknr = WORLD[1].chunknr=global.Values.WORLDVOLUME()` here.
Anyone knows how to bypass that? I belive there's a simply solution...
Do I understand the array of objects correctly?

You can Have like(providing you have the class and constructor)

```
Point POINTARRAY[]= new Point[10];
POINTARRAY[1].x=5
POINTARRAY[1].y=6
POINTARRAY[3].x=17
POINTARRAY[3].y=1
```

Right?
How to assign that via loop?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the following line returns always the same reference:

```
global.Values.CHUNKPATTERN();
```

so the different array indices are actually point to the same referece. It's only a guess because you didn't tell us how the above function works.

Here's an example of what different array element could point to the same instace:

```
public class AClass{ 
  public int val = 0;

 }
AClass[] array = new AClass[2];
AClass classInstance = new AClass();
array[0] = classInstance;
array[1] = classInstance;
```

The code above instatiated a single AClass object (classInstance), but use 2 different array elements to reference the same instance:

```
System.out.println("array 1 value " + array[1].val ); // both element initialized to 0 so it prints 0
array[0].val = 15; // actually is classInstance.val to be modified, through the reference to it stored inside the first element of the array. 
System.out.println("array 1 value " + array[1].val ); // print 15
```

For what concern the POINT example, you can use for loop this way:

```
Point POINTARRAY[]= new Point[10];
for(int i = 0 ; i < POINTARRAY.length; ++i)
{
  POINTARRAY[1].x=...;
  POINTARRAY[1].y=...;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Instead `WORLD[i].chunknr=i+1;` seems to update chunknr of ALL elements.

Are `WORLD[0]` and `WORLD[1]` *different* objects? They are not different if `` `WORLD[0] == WORLD[1] `` evaluates to true.

You have:

```
WORLD[i]=global.Values.CHUNKPATTERN();
```

Does `CHUNKPATTERN` create a `new` object every time it is called?

Answer (score 0):

I bet this method

`WORLD[i]=global.Values.CHUNKPATTERN();`

always returns the same instance of an object so you have a reference to the same object in every slot of your array.

Subsequently

`WORLD[i].chunknr=i+1;`

you change the attribute `chunknr` of the same object in every iteration. You say

> ...seems to update chunknr of ALL elements

kind of true, because all elements reference the same instance.

You need to find a way to have `global.Values.CHUNKPATTERN();` return a new object every time.

Answer (score 0):

This line is your problem:

```
WORLD[i]=global.Values.CHUNKPATTERN();
```

This is assigning `WORLD[i]` a **reference** to `global.Values.CHUNKPATTERN()`, meaning that they both point to the same object! And for each iteration of your loop you are just creating more and more references to the **same** global object.

Sometimes this isn't what you want. In this case you need to **copy** the value, which can be done in a number of ways, but in most cases you can simple clone it. All Java objects support a `clone()` method, although sometimes you need to override it to do the correct thing for your class.

All this means is that you should replace the above line with:

```
WORLD[i]=(YourType)global.Values.CHUNKPATTERN().clone();
```

where `YourType` is the actual type of the class, since you omitted that from the code snippet you posted.

Hope that helps!